# Laravel - How can I conditionally display the input select box based on the radio button selected?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm currently on Laravel 8 with Livewire. There are two input select boxes in a form, how can I conditionally display, either of the select boxes based on the radio button checked. I want to achieve the result without jQuery, please help me.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Need to switch between these two:

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="category_id" class="block">Category ID</label>
    <select wire:model="category_id" name="category_id" id="category_id" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
    </select>
</div>


<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="sub_category_id" class="block">Sub-Category ID</label>
    <select wire:model="sub_category_id" name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_id" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->sub_category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think so it's possible without JS/jQuery.

Comment: @WarrenClarin There is no JavaScript needed for livewire, I guess. There might be something which can be done to achieve the above results.

Comment: For us to give an exact answer, you'll need to share the full code. But, just use an `@if` and check if the property of a checkbox is set or not.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks mate for reaching out, I achieved the current solution using alpine.js, its as easy as tailwind, just two attributes and I'm done. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ToxifiedHashkey mind sharing your solution, otherwise this stays as an open question

Comment: @hugronaphor In such use case you have to use AlpineJs, and conditionally show elements or inputs, if one condition satisfies.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been dead a while so I'll have a crack at an answer.

Assuming your code above, first we need to track something in order to set this state. Great thing is we can use variables from livewire.

In the component define a variable
`public $category_type = "";`

Now bind this to the radio buttons

```
<input wire:model="category_type" type="radio" value="category">
<input wire:model="category_type" type="radio" value="sub_category">
```

So this item in the component will update on change, so we can then just use blade directives to render the required input set

```
@if($category_type == "category")
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="category_id" class="block">Category ID</label>
    <select wire:model="category_id" name="category_id" id="category_id" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
    </select>
</div>
@elseif($category_type == "sub_category")
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="sub_category_id" class="block">Sub-Category ID</label>
    <select wire:model="sub_category_id" name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_id" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->sub_category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
    </select>
</div>
@endif
```

The correct form elements will appear / disappear as you cycle the radio button.
To animate this transition you you probably use some css classes and add remove those.